# Running a batch file from within VB6 code

Tags: vb6

I need to backup an access database from within VB6 code when the user clicks on a commandbutton named "Print". I am thinking that a seperate batch file would be ideal. How would one cause the batch file to run from VB? Once the batch file can be activated, I should be able to use a simple xcopy command to copy the database to a removeable drive. All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Offtopic, but what action should your application perform, when user clicks on a button named "Backup"?

Answer (score 5):

```
Shell("path-to-batch-file", vbHide)
```

Of course if you do not wish to hide it, here's a list of choices.

```
vbHide              0   Window is hidden and focus is passed to the hidden window.
vbNormalFocus       1   Window has focus and is restored to its original size and position.
vbMinimizedFocus    2   Window is displayed as an icon with focus.
vbMaximizedFocus    3   Window is maximized with focus.
vbNormalNoFocus     4   Window is restored to its most recent size and position. The currently active window remains active.
vbMinimizedNoFocus  6   Window is displayed as an icon. The currently active window remains active.
```